# Facial Expression Recognition Data Preparation for CNN

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, face-recognition

I am quite new to the area of facial expression recognition and currently I'm doing a research on this via Deep Learning specifically CNN. I have some questions with regard to preparing and/or preprocessing my data.

I have segmented videos of frontal facial expressions (e.g. 2-3 seconds video of a person expressing a happy emotion based on his/her annotations).

**Note**: expressions displayed by my participants are quite of low intensity (not exaggerated expressions/micro-expressions)

**General Question**: Now, how should I prepare my data for training with CNN (I am a bit leaning on using a deep learning library, TensorFlow)?

**Question 1**: I have read some deep learning-based facial expression recognition (FER) papers that suggest to take the peak of that expression (most probably a single image) and use that image as part of your training data. How would I know the peak of an expression? What's my basis? If I'm going to take a single image, wouldn't some important frames of the subtlety of expression displayed by my participants be lost?

**Question 2**: Or would it be also correct to execute the segmented video in OpenCV in order to detect (e.g. Viola-Jones), crop and save the faces per frame, and use those images as part of my training data with their appropriate labels? I'm guessing some frames of faces to be redundant. However, since we knew that the participants in our data shows low intensity of expressions (micro-expressions), some movements of the face could also be important.

I would really appreciate anyone who can answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @unique monkey already pointed out, this is generally a supervised learning task.  If you wish to extract an independent "peak" point, I recommend that you scan the input images and find the one in each sequence whose reference points deviate most from the subject's resting state.

If you didn't get a resting state, then how are the video clips cropped?  For instance, were the subjects told to make the expression and hold it?  What portion of the total expression (before, express, after) does the clip cover?  Take one or both endpoints of the video clip; graph the movements of the reference points from each end, and look for a frame in which the difference is greatest, but then turns toward the other endpoint.

Comment: Right, that's what I forgot to mention. My data contains spontaneous facial expressions. At first, a subject was being recorded while doing a certain activity for the whole session. After the session, he/she is asked to annotate the whole activity wherein if he/she thinks that a particular expression during a certain period of time in the video is for example happy, he/she would annotate that period of time to be happy. That's the process. Videos were cropped depending on the subjects annotation, so I think it might be a subjective judgement if I would be the one to determine the peak. Thanks

Comment: This implies that you *do* have a resting state on video, then, with the subject's own assessment of being in no particular emotional state.  In that case, my first paragraph applies.

Comment: Speaking to your latter point, yes, it would be useful to use the video clip to express the entire emotion.  However, my understanding of the field says that this is overkill for your application: one representative "peak" frame should suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite enlightened :) I also forgot to mention that in the 2-3 second video clip, there are small movements happening not just still video of a particular expression. That's the reason why I'm quite insisting not to just take one representative "peak" frame. Because of this, as a clarification, it would be okay to use the whole segment of the video clip to express an entire emotion right?

Comment: Yes, it would be okay.  Do note that this time series adds a dimension to your classification problem.  Perhaps you can reduce the complexity by replacing the video with a vector of your reference points over time.  Perhaps you're already doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not familiar with time series. Since I will be using CNN and taking images as input, would it be fine to directly use each frames in a particular video clip as part of my training data?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  "Time series" is when data are presented in some sort of sequenced relationship, and you use the sequencing as part of the classification.  This is often represented as physical juxtaposition.

Answer (score 1):

**answer 1**: Commonly we always depend on human's sense to decide which expression is the peak of the expression(I think you can distinguish the difference in smile and laugh)

**answer 2**: if you want to get a good result, I suggest you not treat data so rude like this method

Comment: **Answer 1**: You're right, it would be quite easy to recognize expressions through human sensing, however, wouldn't it be biased to say that a particular expression is (for example) happy based on my judgement? What if to other people it isn't? How would I know if he/she expresses fear, anger etc?

**Answer 2**: I'm actually neutral on this, can you please justify why is it so if my participants show low intensity of expressions? Aren't the small movements in the face important?

Comment: @Renz you can just judge it by yourself, the problem's key point is that the machine learning model whether could have the same judgement as you or not.....

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not convinced with manually choosing a particular peak of an expression because it can be biased to my understanding. I think if you have some papers that does this would be helpful so I can argue about this confidently. Thanks